# Established data structure/pattern? List with dynamically linked children

Tags: arrays, design-patterns, linked-list

I need a solution where I have one "master" list/array that has a number of sequentially ordered linked children, each one representing a sub-segment of the parent list. It resembles the ["unrolled linked list"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrolled_linked_list) pattern, but here the segment-list size should be dynamic.

Here I will try to explain further. I would like to find out if there's an established term for this kind of data structure/pattern (in the same manner of "graph", "binary tree" etc.) that would be to my help when further investigating this, trying to find the best implementation.

Let's say we have a "master" list with a size of ten items, 0-9, and with three children a, b and c representing sub-segments of the master in the following way:

```
"master"    -------------------
 0-9        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
            ===== ========= ===
"children"  a     b         c
            0-2   3-7       8-9
```

Ideally, the solution should allow

- the master to create and adjust sub-segment size of it's children (depending on rules connected to the master list data items content)
- the children to change their sub-segment size, causing the linked siblings to adjust their size/positions accordingly
- handle under- and overflow of total children sizes compared to master size

Any blogs, articles, code snippets etc that tackles something like this would be to great help! (My solutions will be created in php and as3, but language doesn't matter here).

Thanx!

Comment: Could it be, that the same master has two children (e.g. a and b), or does every master only have one child?

Comment: There should be a one-to-many relationship between master and child...

Comment: I doubt, that you can do a n:m relationship in one array. Of course you could do it in two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want. Build your data structure the other way around. List (or vector) of children nodes and each keeps a list to master node with backlink. Changing sub-segment size in such case would be simple moving of master nodes from one list to another.

```
 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
 \ /     /      \  /
  a-----          b
```

Comment: Thank you, elevener! The reason why I presented it this way ("master" first) is that in my case, I start with a given master list, and deduct the children from that. But maybe it's better to control the structure from the "children perspective"...

Comment: In fact it doesn't changed much. It would be even more convenient. Keep your masters as a list, but still organize master/children link the way I proposed (build children list/links on deduction). In principle you don't need to keep childs in the list in such case, simple traverse with the links from main list, added image